# AttirbuteError: read when trying to post an image using Python Facebook SDK (in a Django proj)

Tags: python, django, facebook-graph-api, django-models, python-imaging-library

In a Django web app of mine, users post photos on the website. Once photos accumulate high enough upvotes, I post them to a Facebook fan page using [this function](https://facebook-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#put-photo) from the Python Facebook SDK. Initial tests of the SDK work correctly. One simply passes a file object representing the image, and a caption to `graph.put_image()` method, and it works.

But I can only get it to work when the image is being uploaded from the client. I'm struggling if an image object is already saved on the server; then the SDK throws an `AttributeError: read` error. I might be making a rookie mistake, so please advise. I get the error when I do:

```
from PIL import Image

api.put_photo(image=Image.open(photo.image_file),message='my caption')
```

Where the photo object is defined as follows in my `models.py`:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    image_file = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_photo, storage=OverwriteStorage())
    upload_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

`OverwriteStorate()` is an overwritten Django `Storage` class (imported from `django.core.files.storage`). It contains functionality to upload to Azure blob storage, and has been working correctly. `upload_photo_to_location` is simply:

```
def upload_photo(instance, filename):
    try:
        blocks = filename.split('.') 
        ext = blocks[-1]
        filename = "%s.%s" % (uuid.uuid4(), ext)
        instance.title = blocks[0]
        return os.path.join('photos/', filename)
    except Exception as e:
        print '%s (%s)' % (e.message, type(e))
        return 0
```

---

The full error traceback:

```
File "/home/myuser/Desktop/myproj/myapp/tasks.py", line 179, in rank_all_photos
    photo_poster(photo.image_file, photo.caption)
  File "/home/myuser/Desktop/myproj/myapp/facebook_api.py", line 14, in photo_poster
    status = api.put_photo(image=Image.open(image_obj),message=caption)
  File "/home/myuser/.virtualenvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/facebook/__init__.py", line 193, in put_photo
    method="POST")
  File "/home/myuser/.virtualenvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/facebook/__init__.py", line 247, in request
    files=files)
  File "/home/myuser/.virtualenvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 50, in request
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/myuser/.virtualenvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 451, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "/home/myuser/.virtualenvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 382, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
  File "/home/myuser/.virtualenvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 307, in prepare
    self.prepare_body(data, files, json)
  File "/home/myuser/.virtualenvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 453, in prepare_body
    (body, content_type) = self._encode_files(files, data)
  File "/home/myuser/.virtualenvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 150, in _encode_files
    fdata = fp.read()
  File "/home/myuser/.virtualenvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 626, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: read
```

Comment: That function expects `open` which is different from `Image.open`.

Comment: @snahor: I used PIL's `Image.open()` when uploading straight from the client - it worked and that threw me off. You're right, it's just using python's inbuilt `open()`. If you include that as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks again!